# MySQL: Music Database Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a big music database with over 8000 tracks in it. For this I need a Search Query that searches in all Colums at once.

That would be no problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE `title` LIKE '%$q%' 
   OR `interpret` LIKE '%$q%' 
   OR `album` LIKE '%$q%' 
ORDER BY interpret ASC, title ASC
```

Okay, nice. Searches my Database and outputs the Result if I put in the Value of one single Colum.

But it should search for Combinations like "interpret - title" or "album - interpret", too.

Some Examples:

- "title"
- "interpret"
- "album"
- "title interpret"
- "title - interpret"
- "album - interpret"
- other Formats like that

Someone who got the Answer for this, or something like a Query I could use?

Comment: In that case you might be better off using a separate table that holds the album properties and its values `(album_id, property_name, property_value)` and then search that table. Otherwise you will have to modify your query to try all possible combinations for a match which will make it more complex if you decide to add new fields in the future.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could post your structure for the tables that you have.

Comment: you might want to consider a fulltext index across those three fields, and then use `match ... against`

Comment: Here is the interesting part of the table structure...
`| id | int(11) | 
| title | varchar(500) | 
| interpret | varchar(500) | 
| album     | varchar(500) | 
| timestamp | timestamp    | 
| lenght    | int(11)      |`